# Accessing Media/Files outside the_content

Tags: uploads, sidebar, the-content

I'm building a site and each post has a PDF file attachment. Is there a way I can access that file outside `the_content()` on a single post page? I'd like to put the file attachment in a sidebar and not in the body of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [WP-Filebase Download plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/). This allowed me to pull the attachments into a shortcode list that I could put in my template file outside `

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment', 
'numberposts' => -1, 
'post_status' => null, 
'post_parent' => $post->ID 
); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment) {
        setup_postdata($attachment);
        the_title();
        the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
        the_excerpt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim - When I do that I get a lot of extra text that doesn't seem to be related to the attachment. I took out `the_title()` and `the_excerpt()` but need to figure out formatting.

Comment: Also would like to figure out how to exclude an attachment from this list -- or better yet set an attachment as "featured" and only display that.

Comment: I ended up using the [WP-Filebase Download plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/). This allowed me to pull the attachments into a shortcode list that I could put in my template file outside `the_content()`.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you expect to receive. Do you you need a shortcode? or better formatting? or both?

Comment: I was searching for a plugin that would allow me to set a "featured attachment" and then use a shortcode or some php on the page to allow for that attachment to be downloaded. Sorry I wasn't clear.