# Plugin writing: access file that was just uploaded

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, filesystem, file-manager

I am having trouble finding a solution for following problem:

The user should upload a file in the menu of my plugin; the file is uploaded to the media folder by using media_handle_upload(file), where the file comes from the _FILES array - this works perfectly. The plugin then, however, should access that very same file (CSV) to extract data and present it on a page via a shortcode.

I can not, however, find out how to access that file in my plugin. I have looked into this: [Access to Media Library](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57554/access-to-media-library), this: [Accessing Media/Files outside the_content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55778/accessing-media-files-outside-the-content), and I have tried to find something in the wordpress codex. So far I could not find anything on this matter, however.

At the moment, my code for reading the file's contents looks like this:

```
$my_file = trailingslashit( wp_upload_dir() ) . 'MyFile.csv';
if (file_exists($my_file)) {
    return file_get_contents($my_file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
} else {
    return "No file found";
}
```

Thus my question is: how does my plugin access a file that is uploaded into the media folder but is not connected to any post or the like? Again, I intend to read the file's contents and process them further.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress StackExchange. You can get attachment id from ```media_handle_upload()``` function. If you can get the id of the uploaded file you can use ```get_attached_file()``` function for getting the full path of the file. Referral of function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file

Comment: that worked, thank you! I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `media_handle_upload()` to upload a file, it creates the attachment post in the database and return the ID of the attachment, or a `WP_Error` if the upload failed. This ID of the attachment is used to access uploaded file.
[**See documentation here.**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/) and an example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/#user-contributed-notes).

So path to your CSV file can be retrieved using `get_attached_file()` as follows:

```
$my_file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id ); // Full path
```

**Documentation for `get_attached_file()` is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/).**
I hope this may help.

Comment: that worked, thank you! I don't know how I missed that